# UX/UI designer books and tutorials

Tags: gui-design

I am venturing into UI/UX design and I would love to dig deeper into this technology, I am a front end engineer html/css/js and I want to learn and be an expert in UI/UX design. If someone could direct me to books and tutorials I have to go through to be a competitive player in this industry.

Comment: Also could you let me know if I which software are needed i.e Photoshop to learn to success in this profession. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: My understanding is UI is an element of UX and these are "pre-development/coding".

Comment: UI/UX not necessarily has to be pre-development/coding. They both can go hand in hand or one can also bring the UI/UX part after the backend of the site is built

Comment: Is it pre-front end coding html/css/js?

Answer (score 0):

There is a book called "**Dont Make Me Think**" by Steve Krug. Now I havent read this book but I have heard great things about this book & that it is a must read.
You can find the book on Amazon [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321344758) You can refer this book for UX

The other really good site which I recently came across is [HackDesign](https://hackdesign.org/) which has some really cool lessons & I think will be really useful to get started

I will keep adding more links as I come across them